# Password is visible in inspect element

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

i made a script that is basicly just a form where you have to put in a password to go to the admin page. when i was doublechecking everything i noticed that can see the script including the password with inspect element. Im still learning php, javascript, html and css and i cant figure out how to put that password in a seperate .js file and link it back to my password code.

This is the code i wrote. i was hoping if someone could learn me how to store the password in a seperate file and link it back

```
<h3>admin<h3>
<form>
    <label for="pswd">Enter your password: </label>
    <input type="password" id="pswd">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="checkPswd();" />
</form>
<!--Function to check password the already set password is Kra5313-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkPswd() {
        var confirmPassword = "kra5313";
        var password = document.getElementById("pswd").value;
        if (password == confirmPassword) {
            window.location="/admin/Stored Ips.php";
        }
        else{
            window.location="/sub pages/you_tried.php";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: JS is client-side so all code is visible to browsers. Normally passwords are stored and compared server-side (PHP). Change your form's _action_ to a PHP script that compares the posted password to one stored server-side (database, text file, ...)

Comment: **never** embed anything potentially secret in either the HTML (within comments etc ) or javascript

Answer (score 0):

Everything inside the script tags is client-side, and the user will see it. That is why there is a backend and a database. To hide things from the user.

Comment: yeah i learned that today by using inspect element on my page haha. i started coding for a school project (IT STUDY) 3 weeks ago so im still pretty new to it!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).